# use variable instead of string in createTextNode()

Tags: javascript, dynamic, html-lists, appendchild, createtextnode

I am trying to add another li to a ul via Javascript. I want the li to have dynamic content depending on an existing variable. I can get it to append a li using a string no problem. Only when I use a variable things go wrong

```
//Adding to List
listOfPlayers.style.display = "block";
var node = document.createElement("LI");
var textnode = document.createTextNode(playerInput.value);
node.appendChild(textnode);
listOfPlayersNumerated.appendChild(node);
```

The problem lays with:

```
var textnode = document.createTextNode(playerInput.value);
```

I have tried a literal string (as seen below) and it worked not problem

```
var textnode = document.createTextNode("New Player");
```

Comment: where do you declare `playerInput.value`?

Comment: What is  `playerInput.value`?

Comment: `var x = 'hello'; document.createTextNode(x);` works fine if you stick it in the console.  So that would suggest the variable you are using is problematic.

Comment: I tried it on Codepen and it worked. I think you have a different issue here.

Comment: I declare playerInput.value a little higher `var playerInput = document.getElementById("playerInput");` @dwosk @VLAZ

Comment: Show the complete code....

Comment: @epascarello there is not much else to show. I did forget to show where I declared playerInput. but the rest of the code is not particularly relevant. I don't want to show a couple of hundred lines of code and make you sort though it

Answer (score 0):

So I changed it up so you can see where the variable is coming from...

Up top:

```
var inputPlayer = document.getElementById("inputPlayer");
```

Then I just add .value to get the value of that input below:

```
//Adding to List
listOfPlayers.style.display = "block";
var playerName = playerInput.value;
console.log(playerName);
var node = document.createElement("LI");
var textnode = document.createTextNode(playerName);
node.appendChild(textnode);
listOfPlayersNumerated.appendChild(node);
```

it will log it in the console but it does not appear on the ul

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I believe it did not like the scope. despite printing out the variable in the console. I moved

```
var playerName = playerInput.value;
```

Up and out of the current function. weird the console.log() would accept it but not .createTextNode() in that scope

So by moving where the new variable is declared outside the function it seems to have **solved the issue**